# Connection Only on merged Power Queries

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have two queries in my workbook that rely on each other.  One is set to a connection only, the other is set to load to a table after performing some merging and expanding operations.  I noticed that when refreshing, the query set to "Connection only" does not have a visual indication of refreshing.

When I refresh the secondary query that relies on information from the connection only one, does it actually refresh both of them?  I am having a hard time finding clear documentation on this.  A link to where the information is would also be appreciated.

Further information on the queries themselves:

- Both link to SQL tables.
- One pulls the latest data available in the table.
- The other pulls recent information from a different table.
- The second one merges the two tables together (by the key).
- The second one then only grabs information from the first when there is missing information in the second.

I am specifically asking; When the second table calls a refresh, does the first table also refresh even though it is a connection only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes effectively the first query is also refreshed - it's query definition is run and the result is pulled into your second query.

Note in the Query Editor window you will see a "Preview" dataset for your first query, which would not be refreshed by your refresh of the second query. That "Preview" dataset is only a design tool, it doesn't affect your results when you actually refresh and deliver data into an Excel table.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I was having a hard time observing the behavior on my own due to the nature of my data sources.  The preview is what cause me a little concern about the final functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a tough time finding information about this. There is a post by [Ken Puls in PowerPivotPro.com](https://powerpivotpro.com/2017/07/power-query-refresh-speeds-suck/) that helps drive some (good) conclusions about this. Net-net, the "connection only" queries ARE refreshed before the merge query, you just don't see it (which, btw, I think should be implemented in Excel). Hope this helps.